# Video as a Splash Screen instead of Picture - Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to add video in my splash screen .. Is it possible in Ionic 2 ? I checked some link but it was not worth like [Video as splash screen on phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263206/video-as-splash-screen-on-phonegap) .In video I can show skip when app loaded properly .

reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvzvNfXvNDs

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no cordova plugin out there supporting video or animated gif.

But you may be able to hack it if you [get your hands dirty with some java code](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/09/how-to-create-splash-activity-best.html).

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: i checked that but i am looking for any alternative . i don't want to update in that java file

Comment: I am convinced going down with Java is the only way, and it's going to be tricky. Best of luck. Make sure to post it here if you achieve that or find another solution.

Comment: I am play video in first page. is there any proper way to show video on startup.